# Clone HTML div while changing all ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this, simplified for testing, architecture :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row_0">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form id="form_0">
        <select name="test1" id="test1_0"></select>
        <select name="test2" id="test2_0"></select>
        <input name="test3" id="test3_0"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my goal is to clone that row in the container, while changing EVERY `_0` and incrementing it by 1.

I'm able to clone a the row, get the numeric value of the row and create another row with an incremented id.

```
var div = $('div[class^="row"]:last');
var num = parseInt( div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
var clone = div.clone().prop('id', 'row_'+num );

div.after( clone );
```

But I have no idea how to change each and every id that has a `_0` to `_1`, can anyone help me please?

Fiddle exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/L5mn63g7/1/

Comment: Do you need to ids at all? They're often an anti-pattern because of having to create hacky solutions around problems such as this. A much better idea would be to use common classes and use DOM traversal in the event handlers on the HTML you inject to find related information.

Comment: `change each and every id`. So, if there are more than 1 element with class `row`, how many elements will be cloned and changed the id after clicking on `Clone` button?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan seeing my full architecture it's inevitable for me to use this kind of ids unless I do some serious change in the code which I can not. Is it not possible as it is?

Comment: Of course it's possible, it's just not nice.  You might also need to handle events differently.

Comment: @TânNguyễn only one is cloned each time, which the id incremented depending on the last one added.

Comment: @freedomn-m I don't mind it being not nice, I don't have a choice at this stage unfortunately... Would you mind giving me a hint please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $row = $('.row').last(); //Select the row
var num = parseInt($row.attr('id').match(/\d+$/)[0]) + 1; //get the current index
var clone = $row.clone(); //clone the row
clone.attr('id', 'row_' + num); //change its id
clone.children('[id]').each(function() {//go through all elements with an id
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(/\d+$/, num)); //change the id
});
clone.appendTo('body'); //append the result to the body (replace 'body' with where you want it)
```

*This code has **not** been tested, it might contain bugs or errors.*

However I agree with Rory McCrossan :
You could just place each row in a div with a specific id, then call insider classes with `var $row = $('#div_id'); $row.find('.class')` (I'm using this for an included form)

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = $('div[id^="row"]:last');
var num = parseInt( div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
var clone = div.clone().prop('id', 'row_'+num );
clone.find('[id]').each(function(){var $this = $(this); $this.prop('id', $this.prop('id').split('_')[0] + '_' + num);});  
div.after( clone );
```

Comment: How is this answer different than the other?